# More than one Singleton in a single servlet container (Tomcat)

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have my own framework for building java web app, and within that framework, I create my own Threadpool executor service which is singleton. So, each web app that using my framework will create 1 Threadpool executor on startup, to be use internally.

My questions are:

1. Let say I deploy 2 web apps in the same Tomcat, would those 2 Threadpools interfere each other?
2. Is there any possibility where a thread from the 1st web app would accessing the Threadpool from the 2nd web app, or vice versa?
3. Do I need to create a single Threadpool service for all my web apps that resides in a single servlet container, instead of one for each web app?

Thank you.

Comment: Putting singletons in a multithreaded web app is a bad idea. I like the service idea but not so much a thread pool as a resource or resources that all instances of the application can "call" to do whatever it is you do in those threads. If they spin off asynchronous threads, it isolates that work from the web app having to think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No. The webapps should be isolated by ClassLoader within Tomcat, so each should have their own instance of the singleton.
2. So long as the answer to #1 is in fact no, then the answer to this is also no.
3. Probably not.

As an aside, my understanding is that, as a general rule Java EE web apps are not supposed to spin up new threads.

Comment: With JavaEE 7 we finally can use the container to spin up new threads.

Comment: Philippe, its great JEE 7 can do that, but currently I'm using Tomcat 7 which is only a Servlet container, I planned to use Glassfish thou .. the centralize Threadpool executor would be a nice way to go.

Any other answer? from others as second opinion?